# memory/cpu utilization issues when running dask on cluster (SGE)

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, sungridengine

I ported my code that uses pandas to dask (basically replaced pd.read_csv with dd.read_csv). The code essentially applies a series of filters/transformations on the (dask) dataframe. Similarly, I use dask bag/array instead of numpy array-like data. The code works great locally (i.e., on my workstation or on a virtual machine). However, when I run the code to a cluster (SGE), my jobs gets killed by the scheduler saying that memory/cpu usage have exceeded the allocated limit. It looks like dask is trying to consume all memory/threads available on the node as opposed to what has been allocated by the scheduler. There seem to be two approaches to fix this issue - (a) set memory/cpu limits for dask from within the code as soon as we load the library (just like we set matplotlib.use("Agg") as soon as we load matplotlib when we need to set the backend) and/or (b) have dask understand the memory limits set by the scheduler. Could you please help on how to go about this issue. My preference would be to set mem/cpu limits for dask from within the code. PS: I understand there is a way to spin up dask workers in a cluster environment and specify these limits, but I am interested in running my code that works great locally on the cluster with minimal additional changes. Thanks!

Comment: How are you starting dask on the SGE cluster ?  Have you looked at https://jobqueue.dask.org ?  Specifically, https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/configuration-setup.html for memory configuration